# JavaScript - Join arrays of an array with concat method instead of push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, nested-loops, concatenation

I have a problem that asks me to join arrays of an array and return a single array in the form of `[ array[0][0], array[0][1], array[1][0], array[1][1], etc. ]`. I solved it using the `push` method in nested for-loops, but the prompt says that I should be familiar with the `concat` method. I know the `concat` method syntax and how it works, but I can't figure out how to use it to do what the prompt asks for.

Here's my solution using the `push` method:

```
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var joined = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
      joined.push(arr[i][k]);
    }
  } 
  return joined;
}

joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);

// => [ 1, 4, true, false, 'x', 'y' ]
```

How would I return the same output using the `concat` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use concatenation, you wouldn't need the second loop, you can just concatenate each sub array within a single loop. One thing to remember is that [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) doesn't modify exist array but returns a new one:

```js
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var joined = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    joined = joined.concat(arr[i]) // concat sub array
  } 
  return joined;
}

console.log(
  joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']])
);
```

You can also use a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in a similar manner:

```js
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var joined = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    joined = [...joined, ...arr[i]] // spread
  } 
  return joined;
}

console.log(
  joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']])
);
```

Using `reduce`, [as suggested by J. Guilherme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113931/3928341), is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Thank you! I had everything except for the the assignment of `joined` to the concat method.

Comment: @Michael glad to help mate :)

Comment: With rest and spread: `var joinArrayOfArrays = (...args)=>[].concat(...args);`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new. Now I see that the reason I couldn't get the solution using array concatenation is that I was assuming concat modified the existing array. So thanks also for that key piece of information.

Answer (score 4):

Try using reduce:

```
arr.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e))
```

Comment: No need for the second `[]` argument. When you omit it, it means you want to use the first item in the array as the starting value. Also, a little white space doesn't hurt anyone: `arr.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e))`

Comment: thank you for your advices! i've just made an edit to implement this tips.

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread element preceding array as parameter to `.concat()`

```js
let res = [].concat(...[[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);

console.log(res);
```

Using a function

```js
const joinArrayOfArrays = (arrays = []) => [].concat(...arrays);

let res = joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to practice your array methods, I suggest looking up the reduce method on MDN and adapt this solution to this problem as an alternative to a for-loop:

```
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
      }); 
    }

    var output = joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);
    console.log(output); 
    // [1, 4, true, false, "x", "y"]
```

Comment: Thanks! This particular problem was asking specifically for the concat method but I'll definitely do that.